# Selenium Copy from Embedded PDF Not Saving Text to Clipboard

Tags: java, selenium, pdf

Our site has a link to open a PDF in another browser window.  I'm using Selenium and the Chrome Web Driver to test the contents of that PDF are accurate.  I am trying to copy the text contents of the PDF to the clipboard, so I can then inspect the text.  Below is the Java code I have so far after digging through Stack Overflow for possible solutions.

```
WebElement body = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body"));
body.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a"));
sleep(500);
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.contextClick(body).build().perform();
act.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).perform();
act.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).perform();
```

The solution above does highlight all of the text in the PDF window and opens the context menu; however, the ARROW DOWN moves the PDF window down -- it doesn't move the cursor down into the first element in the context menu.  I have also tried simply using sendKeys to send a Ctrl+C, but that option didn't actually copy anything into the clipboard.

Comment: Try adding `sleep` between yout `act` commands

Comment: @Ivan Pronin, I tried that, but it didn't work; I had also previously tried debugging through the code before posting here -- in effect, adding sleeps as I waited for a bit to step over the next line of code.

Comment: Did you have any luck with this? I posted a similar question just today, and haven't had any luck.